# Accessing Interop.office.excel library from asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop

i have an asp.net web application and deployed on web server. in a scenario i have a fixed format excel sheet which is on server in a web folder. at runtime i m writing in cell with the help of `interop.office.excel` library. initially there was no excel installed on server then we have installed excel and given COM component full rights from Component services. but now we are getting below error. How to solve this ?

> Detection of product '{90110409-6000-11D3-8CFE-0150048383C9}', feature
>   'OfficeUserData', component '{4A31E933-6F67-11D2-AAA2-00A0C90F57B0}'
>   failed.  The resource 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\MS
>   Access Database\' does not exist.
>
> Detection of product '{90110409-6000-11D3-8CFE-0150048383C9}', feature
>   'ExcelUserData', component '{8ADD2C96-C8B7-11D1-9C67-0000F81F1B38}'
>   failed.  The resource
>   'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\UserData' does
>   not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Interop is not supported in sever-scenarios (like ASP.NET) by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).**

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.