# Export HTML Div To Excel 2007(xslx)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to export HTML Div to Excel 2007 or Higher
I could export Div to Excel 2003 only 
Is there is any way to export to excel 2007(xslx) 
thanks for All

Comment: Yes. [You can write XLS files from vb.net](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/WriteToExcel2007.php)

Comment: PowerShell might also be a good choice.

Comment: Please see the following article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699311/accessing-interop-office-excel-library-from-asp-net-web-application

Comment: I would not use Interop in conjunction with ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that could get you going.

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        DoIt()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoIt()
        Dim officeApp As New excel.Application() 'make an instance of Excel
        Dim workBook As excel.Workbook 'make an instance of a WorkBook
        workBook = officeApp.Workbooks.Add 'put a WorkBook in that instance you just made
        Dim workSheet As excel.Worksheet 'make an instance of a Worksheet
        workSheet = workBook.Sheets(1) 'put a sheet in that Instance
        workSheet.Cells(1, 1).value = "This is my value" 'modify the value of cell 1,1
        workBook.SaveAs("c:\temp\myxls.xls") 'save the Excel file.
    End Sub
End Module
```